# Gaussian data fit varying depending on position of x data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, data-fitting

I am having a hard time trying to understand why my Gaussian fit to a set of data (`ydata`) does not work well if I shift the interval of x-values corresponding to that data (`xdata1` to `xdata2`). The Gaussian is written as:

[image]

where A is just an amplitude factor. Changing some of the values of the data, it is easy to make it work for both cases, but one can also easily find cases in which it does not work well for `xdata1` and also in which covariance of the parameters is not estimated.
I am using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` in Spyder with Python 3.7.1 on Windows 7.

[image: results from code]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata1 = np.linspace(-9,4,20, endpoint=True) # works fine
xdata2 = xdata1+2
ydata = np.array([8,9,15,12,14,20,24,40,54,94,160,290,400,420,300,130,40,10,8,4])

def gaussian(x, amp, mean, sigma):
    return amp*np.exp(-(((x-mean)**2)/(2*sigma**2)))/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))

popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(gaussian, xdata1, ydata)
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(gaussian, xdata2, ydata)

fig, ([ax1, ax2]) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2,figsize=(9, 4))

ax1.plot(xdata1, ydata, 'b+:', label='xdata1')
ax1.plot(xdata1, gaussian(xdata1, *popt1), 'r-', label='fit')
ax1.legend()
ax2.plot(xdata2, ydata, 'b+:', label='xdata2')
ax2.plot(xdata2, gaussian(xdata2, *popt2), 'r-', label='fit')
ax2.legend()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your second attempt at fitting a gaussian is getting stuck in a local minimum while searching parameter space: curve_fit is a wrapper for [least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) which uses gradient descent to minimize the cost function and this is liable to get [stuck in local minima](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24534/does-gradient-descent-always-converge-to-an-optimum).

You should try providing reasonable starting parameters (by using the `p0` argument of [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)) to avoid this:

```
 #...  your code

 y_max = np.max(y_data)
 max_pos = ydata[ydata==y_max][0]
 initial_guess = [y_max, max_pos, 1] # amplitude, mean, std

 popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(gaussian, xdata2, ydata, p0=initial_guess)
```

Which as you can see provides a reasonable fit:

[image: gaussian_fits_with_parameters]

You should write a function which can provide reasonable estimates of the starting parameters. Here I just found the maximum *y* value and used this to determine the initial parameters. I've found this works well for the fitting normal distributions but you could consider other methods.

**Edit:**

You can also solve the problem by scaling the amplitude: the amplitude is so large the parameter space is distorted and the gradient descent simply follows the direction of greatest change in the amplitude and effectively ignores the sigma. Consider the following plot in parameter space (Colour is the sum of the squared residuals of the fit for given parameters and the white cross shows the optimal solution):

[image: full_parameter_space]

Make sure to make note of the different scales for the x and y axis.

One needs to make a large number of 'unit' sized steps in y (amplitude) to get to the minimum from the point x,y = (0,0), where as you only need less than one 'unit' sized step to get to the minimum in x (sigma). The algorithm simply takes steps in amplitude as this is the steepest gradient. When it gets to the amplitude which minimises the cost function it simply stops the algorithm as it appears to have converged and makes little or no changes in the sigma parameter.

One way to fix this is to scale your ydata to un-distort the parameter space: divide your `ydata` by 100 and you will see your fit works without providing any starting parameters!

Comment: Probably a better approach would be to normalize your data before fitting it, i.e. re-scale it to have zero mean and unit variance. In fact, if you know that your data is normal distributed that already provides the parameters you were looking for.

Comment: You could calculate these starting parameters (i.e. calculate variance and mean and use these as your `p0`) and I think this would have the same result? Is there a reason this would perform better?

The approach I presented here has the advantage that you don't need to transform your data.

Comment: Well, in fact if your data points are an sampled from a normal distribution, then the sample mean and variance are the maximum likelihood estimators for the mean and variance of the underlying distribution, i.e. they provide the optimal estimate of this parameters. If the data is not sampled from a normal distribution, this is of course not true, so you have a fair point about the asymetry.

Comment: Sure, I agree, but I think that's beside the point. I don't think the OP necessarily said there data was sampled from a normal distribution. It looks like there data maybe from an experiment. 

I suggest you frame these comments into an answer in case someone is sampling from a normal distribution as It is a nice discussion. I will leave my answer: it is quite general, you can test if your data conforms with the assumption of it being normally distributed and if not easily fit another function.

Comment: Agree, I think the points you made are all correct :) I was a bit too fast with my first comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on providing an initial guess and highlighting how the `curve_fit` works, @FChm, it is indeed a nice approach to tackle the fitting. Thank you also for the comments, @FChm, @user1587520, the data was not sampled from a normal distribution.